# Не упорядочиваются элементы по убыванию.Что не так?

Tags: c#, матрицы

Сначала в программе меняются местами наибольший и наименьший элемент матрицы,а дальше каждая строка должна быть упорядочена по убыванию,но мне выводит только измененную матрицу1. Что не так?

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите k");
int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите n");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] a = new int[k, n];
int max = int.MinValue;
int min = int.MaxValue;
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        a[i, j] = random.Next(0, 10);
}
Console.WriteLine("Исходная матрица:");

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i, j]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
int iMax = 0, jMax = 0, jMin = 0, iMin = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (a[i, j] > max)
        {
            max = a[i, j];
            iMax = i;
            jMax = j;
        }
        if (a[i, j] < min)
        {
            min = a[i, j];
            iMin = i;
            jMin = j;
        }
    }
}
a[iMin, jMin] = max;
a[iMax, jMax] = min;
Console.WriteLine("Измененная матрица1:");
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i, j]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Измененная матрица2:");
int x = 0;
for (int m = 0; m < k; m++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (a[m, j] < a[m, j++])
        {
            x += a[m, j];
            a[m, j] = a[m, j++];
            a[m, j++] = x;
        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i, j]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}        
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: У вас алгоритм неправильный. Советую для начала написать его псевдокодом "на бумажке", дальше записать в терминах `C#` не составит труда.

Comment: Алгоритм какой сортировки вы хотите применить?

Comment: элементов каждой строки по убыванию @FoggyFinder

Comment: Хм, имел ввиду немного другое. Давайте возьмем самую очевидную - сортировку пузырьком. Вы знаете её принцип ?

Comment: проверить всю матрицу и менять местами  рядом стоящие элементы строк? @FoggyFinder

Comment: не совсем. Представьте, что строка матрицы это просто отдельный набор данных не связанный с остальной частью. Попробуйте написать код для сортировки одномерного массива, если у вас все получится правильно, то вы без труда добавите внешний цикл который будет двигаться по строкам матрицы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный ресурс не предназначен для исправления домашних заданий. Тем не менее, я подробно разберу основные ошибки, а уж как их применить к вашему решению придется подумать самостоятельно. Вы ведь сюда не за халявой пришли, а за знаниями?

**1. Использование оператора ++**

Оператор ++ это комбинированный оператор, который увеличивает текущее значение переменной на 1. Обращаю внимание нато, что это изменение не временное, а постоянное. Несколько примеров:

Простейший случай

```
x++;
//или
++x;
//эквивалентная запись
x = x + 1;
```

В составном выражении
Первый случай (увеличение на единицу после использования)

```
int x = 1, y = 0;
y = x++;
//эквивалентная запись
y = x;
x = x + 1;
//в результате y=1, x=2
```

Второй случай (увеличение на единицу перед использованием)

```
int x = 1, y = 0;
y = ++x;
//эквивалентная запись
x = x + 1;
y = x;
//в результате y=2, x=2
```

Все тоже самое относится и к оператору `--`. Думаю разницу заметить не сложно.

**2. Оператор +=**

С этим оператором проще, сразу перейду к эквивалентной записи:

```
x += y;
//эквивалент
x = x + y;
//но никак не x = y;
```

Не стоит использовать сокращенные записи выражений если не понимаете полностью как это работает. Сокращенные записи предназначены для уменьшения объема кода действительно больших программ, а в учебных программах они лишь запутывают понимание работы алгоритма.

Теперь обратим внимание на фрагмент из вашего кода:

```
//первый проход по циклу
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
//предполагается, что значение j уведичится после окончания цикла, 
//а во время выполнеия будет равно 0
{
    if (a[m, j] < a[m, j++])//сравниваем a[m,0] и a[m,0]
    //увеличение после использования. после сравнения j = 1
    {
        //код который был тут никогда не выполнится, т.к. x < x == false
    }
    //первый проход закочен, цикл увеличивает счестчик на один
    //на втором проходе j = 2, а должно быть 1. 
}
```

Ошибок тут две. Первая - никогда не применяйте операторы `++` и `--` к счетчику цикла `for` внутри самого цикла, это нарушает последовальность значений принимаемых счетчиком, во всяком случае пока не освоитесь с базовыми алгоритмами. И вторая - неправильное применение поератора `++` привлело к сравнению неправильных элементов, вместо этого нужно было написать `j+1`.

Ок. Исправим `if`, что дальше?

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    if (a[m, j] < a[m, j+1])
    {
        x += a[m, j];//вы уверены, что хотите получить в x сумму всех подходящих элементов?
        a[m, j] = a[m, j++];//a[m,j] = a[m,j], а смысл?
        a[m, j++] = x;//тут вроде бы все хорошо, a[m, j+1] = x,
        //только вот значение a[m, j+1] затерлось новым значением
        //ну и счетчик цикла, как и в прошлый раз сбился, если в первый раз 
        //через один, то теперь через два.
    }
}
```

**3. Почему не работает сортировка**

Начнем с того, что представленный фрагмент кода не содержит алгоритма сортировки.

Из простых алгоритмов сортировки вам должны были рассказывать три:
- сортировка пузырьком
- сортировка выбором
- сортировка вставками

Таким образом, применительно к матрице и ожидаемому результату алгоритм должен выглядеть так (псевдокод)

```
//для каждой строки матрицы
for(int i = 0; i < n i++)
{
    //Сортируем строку с индексом i
}
```

Любой из перечисленных выше алгоритмов сортировки легко найти в сети по его названию, включая рабочий исходный код на C#, так что это также останется для самостоятельной работы.

Практический совет: не ограничивайтесь простым копированием найденного исходника, разберитесь как он работает и потренируйтесь на одномерном массиве, как уже советовал в комментариях [**@Foggy Finder**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227049/foggy-finder).

Потом примените этот же алгоритм к строке матрицы, разница будет заключаться только в том, что для двумерного массива, номер строки будет задаваться переменной из внешнего цикла.